# Create an Info/Help message at top of a custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types

I'm wondering how you go about creating an info/help message at the top of a custom post type in WP's dashboard? I often see these at the top of plugins and Id like to do the same thing for my custom post types if possible (*see image below for example --- Note: Screenshot has been taken from [NSP-Code's "Post-Types Order" plugin](http://www.nsp-code.com/wordpress-plugins/post-types-order/) on the settings page"*)

[image]

## EDIT #1

Thanks for the help everyone! It appears that I have two distinctly different ways available to me in how I can approach this as outlined by @Stephen & @Bainternet...Both look like viable options so Im going to try them all out and report back with what seems to work best in my situation.

Thanks again for the assistance. WPSE is by far my fav place to learn new things about Wordpress, this place is great.

Comment: You mean [post types](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types) or [post formats](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Formats)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The hook you are after is [`admin_notices`](http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/hook/admin_notices). This is fired at the top of *every* admin page.

If you wish to restrict the notice to certain pages you can use: [get_current_screen()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_current_screen) to get the current screen.

```
 $screen = get_current_screen();
```

You can wrap the notices in `div` elements with class 'error' or 'updated' to get the red, or yellow styled notices.

For instance:

```
function wpse51463_admin_notice(){
      $screen = get_current_screen();

    //If not on the screen with ID 'edit-post' abort.
    if( $screen->id !='edit-post' )
        return;

      ?>

      <div class="updated">
        <p>
        A notice on the post list screen
        </p>
      </div>

      <div class="error">
        <p>
        An error message
        </p>
      </div>

     <?php

 }
 add_action('admin_notices','wpse51463_admin_notice');
```

For a plug-ins settings page (nested under the Settings tab) the screen id should be `settings_page_{page-name}`. You can of course determine the id of a page by using the above to print the current screen id of every page.

Comment: This solution seemed to work best for my needs, thank you for the thorough explanation as well!

Answer (score 4):

If you want something like this:

[image]

Then here's something that does the job:

```
add_action('admin_footer','print_mynote');
function print_mynote(){
    global $typenow,$pagenow;
    if  (in_array( $pagenow, array( 'post.php', 'post-new.php' ))  && "Post_Type_Name" == $typenow ) {
        ?>
        <SCRIPT TYPE="text/javascript">
            jQuery(document).ready(function(){
                var myDiv = jQuery('<div>');
                myDiv.css("border","1px dashed #000000");
                myDiv.css("padding","5px");
                myDiv.css("background","lightyellow");
                myDiv.css("width","70%");
                myDiv.html("PUT your info help message here....");
                jQuery(".wrap").find("h2").after(myDiv);
            });
        </SCRIPT>
    <?php
    }
}
```

Just make sure you change `Post_Type_Name` to the name of your post type, and change `PUT your info help message here....` to your actual message.